# Dollar Sign ($) gets removed from Facet on Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to create 4 scatter plots on 1 figure. Each facet contains title that has `$` sign. In 2 out of 4 facet the `$` sign gets removed. Can some one explain why and how to add `$` sign? Also I need to remove `Category =` from the facet title how can I do that?

Below is the code to replicate the results

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Price':[1.5,3,10,20],
    'Mcap':[20,30,40,50],
    'Category':['Price <= $2', '$2 < Price <= $5', '$5 < Price <= $15', 
            'Price > $15'],
    'MRR':[20,30,40,50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


plot = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Category", col_wrap=2, height=4,
                    sharey = False)
plot.map(sns.scatterplot, "MRR", "Mcap",alpha=.7)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a backslash for escaping and Set the titles of the subplots as a list.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Price':[1.5,3,10,20],
    'Mcap':[20,30,40,50],
    'Category':['Price <= \$2', '\$2 < Price <= \$5', '\$5 < Price <= \$15', 
            'Price > \$15'],
    'MRR':[20,30,40,50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


plot = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Category", col_wrap=2, height=4,
                    sharey = False)
plot.map(sns.scatterplot, "MRR", "Mcap",alpha=.7)

sub_title = df['Category'].tolist()
for ax, title in zip(plot.axes.flat, sub_title):
    ax.set_title(title)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The solution answers the first question. Can you also tell how to get rid of `Category =` from title so I can accept this answer.

Comment: Another requirement was overlooked. The code and output graphs have been updated.